# The config profile (myawsprofile) could not be found

Tags: aws-cli

i am facing a problem

I configures aws-cli in my machine and created a new profile:

```
aws configure --profile myawsprofile
```

I created this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-ubuntu --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name mypemfile --security-group-ids sg-mine  --subnet-id subnet-mine --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=AWSTEST}]" --output text --profile myawssprofile
```

And tryed to run the script as admin

```
sudo bash myscript
```

I got this error: **The config profile (myawsprofile) could not be found**

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!!
I had to create my profile using sudo also.

```
sudo aws configure --profile myawsprofile
```

And it worked!!
Thanks